# Javascript works until saved

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I have inserted some JavaScript into a Script Web Part. Just a button that adds some columns to a SharePoint list.

It works when I click the preview button on the Insert Snippet/Embed page. It works when I click Insert Snippet and get back to edit on the SharePoint page. But when I save the page, it stops working.

Any ideas?

(SharePoint Online 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Never used SharePoint Online 2013 but try placing your Javascript code in the body section of the web part instead of the header section. On Sharepoint 2010, I had an issue where my Javascript wouldn't run as a webpart but it worked after I moved the Javascript code from header to body.